# How to force WKWebView to ignore hardware silent switch on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

The ask here is to play all kinds of web sounds regardless of the hardware silent switch , both muted and not muted devices **must keep playing** the sound in HTML pages while the app is foregrounded.
The solution for *deprecated* `UIWebView` is quite easy

```
let localWebView = UIWebView(frame: .zero)
localWebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
localWebView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
```

How the same behavior can be achieved for `WKWebView`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update**: Added new hack working flawlessly also on iOS 14 and newer (reflected in code, see bottom for extra details).
Since I have a solution to this nontrivial problem, I'd like to share it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didBecomeActive),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willResignActive),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []
    wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
}

@objc func willResignActive() {
    disableIgnoreSilentSwitch(wkWebView)
}

@objc func didBecomeActive() {
    //Always creates new js Audio object to ensure the audio session behaves correctly
    forceIgnoreSilentHardwareSwitch(wkWebView, initialSetup: false)
}
```

And most importantly in `WKNavigationDelegate`:

```
private func disableIgnoreSilentSwitch(_ webView: WKWebView) {
    //Muting the js Audio object src is critical to restore the audio sound session to consistent state for app background/foreground cycle
    let jsInject = "document.getElementById('wkwebviewAudio').muted=true;"
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsInject, completionHandler: nil)
}

private func forceIgnoreSilentHardwareSwitch(_ webView: WKWebView, initialSetup: Bool) {
    //after some trial and error this seems to be minimal silence sound that still plays
    let silenceMono56kbps100msBase64Mp3 = "data:audio/mp3;base64,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"
    //Plays 100ms silence once the web page has loaded through HTML5 Audio element (through Javascript)
    //which as a side effect will switch WKWebView AudioSession to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback

    var jsInject: String
    if initialSetup {
       jsInject =
            "var s=new Audio('\(silenceMono56kbps100msBase64Mp3)');" +
            "s.id='wkwebviewAudio';" +
            "s.play();" +
            "s.loop=true;" +
            "document.body.appendChild(s);"
    } else {
        //Restore sound hack
        jsInject = "document.getElementById('wkwebviewAudio').muted=false;"
    }
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsInject, completionHandler: nil)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    //As a result the WKWebView ignores the silent switch
    forceIgnoreSilentHardwareSwitch(webView, initialSetup: true)
}
```

Interestingly a related Safari problem is mentioned here: [IOS WebAudio only works on headphones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122418/ios-webaudio-only-works-on-headphones/46839941#46839941) where @Spencer Evans workaround looks very similar to mine.

However when I tried to apply his shorter base64 silence sound it didn't work for `WKWebView`, so I'm providing my own minimal silence sound tested on iOS12.

**Why it works?**

Playing an `<audio>` or `<video>` element (which in the workaround happens to be non audible silence) changes `WKWebView` audio session category from `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`. This will be valid until next load request resets it.

It's all great till the app is backgrounded. But upon subsequent foregrounding things will break in 2 possible ways:

- user needs to tap for the sounds to reappear
- rarely no user input will help and the WKWebView lands in semi frozen state

To **counter** that^ the hack is reverted with `disableIgnoreSilentSwitch(wkWebView)` and later reenabled with `forceIgnoreSilentHardwareSwitch(wkWebView, initialSetup: false)`

Since `WKWebView` core runs in an external process it cannot be accessed the way `UIWebView` shared (with our app) `AVAudioSession` can be.

**Verified** for:
iOS 11.4
iOS 12.4.1
iOS 13.3
iOS 14.1
iOS 14.5.1
iOS 14.8
iOS 15.0
iOS 16.0

**iOS 14 update**
Situation got pretty bad in iOS 14 where obsolete audio tag `.src=null` trick stopped working. Technically `.src=null` does work for a very short window of time (one can revert the hack using `.src` during initial setup). However once the silence loop is playing it becomes useless.

The new trick relies on `.mute` which miraculously works across all iOS versions including iOS14 (but only when accessing documentById directly not a var). No mediacenter when locking the screen neither. It took a lot of research, but we got it.

Comment: I do not manage to implement your code. Where this part should go ?
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []
let localWebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)

Comment: @bablack you can put it in viewDidLoad, depends on your needs.

Comment: ok thx and why let localWebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration) ? and also how use the webView func ?...sorry beginner..

Comment: These are separate questions way beyond this one. If you have trouble using `WKWebView` please check existing questions on SO and maybe some tutorials. If that does not help ask a new question on SO describing your particular problem/challenge in details.

Comment: This is amazing (even though little hacky) solution! Thanks!

Comment: Its so hacky but it works.. no need of AVAudioSession. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling the setupAudio method inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

```
private func setupAudio() {
    do {
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try audioSession.setActive(false)
        try audioSession.setCategory(.playback, options: [])
    } catch (let error) {
        print("Audio error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I did try this 3 years ago. It won’t work because Webkit of `WKWebView` is running as an external process, hence you cannot affect its `AVAudioSession` because it’s not the same instance as the one belonging to your app. That’s the very reason why the js trick was invented. Your approach would work for deprecated `UIWebView`