# Enable inLine media playback for SwiftUI on videos loaded through WKWebView

Tags: xcode, swiftui

Below is the code that I currently have. How do I enable inline media playback for swiftUI? I want the video to automatically play when the webview is appeared. Below is the code I have so far. Thanks in advance.

```
Button(action: {
                    self.isPlayed.toggle()//toggles the boolean isPlayed
                    self.appear.toggle()//toggles the boolean appear


                }, label: {

                    //if the boolean of isPlayed and
                    if isPlayed && appear{
                        Image(systemName: "pause")
                            .font(Font.system(size: 30))

                    } else{
                        Image(systemName:"play")
                            .font(Font.system(size: 30))
                    }

                })
                Spacer()
                }

            if appear == true{

               WebView(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http:www.\(websites[counter])?playsinline=1")!))
                   .frame(width:300, height:300)
                .padding()
                .opacity(1)

            }

        }

        }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let request: URLRequest//pass the website to webkit

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()

    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(request)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be done via `WKWebViewConfiguration` as below

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
    return webView
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! However the audio seems to auto mute... but I've also heard that this has to do with the browser?

Comment: There is known workaround, please read [How to force WKWebView to ignore hardware silent switch on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460362/how-to-force-wkwebview-to-ignore-hardware-silent-switch-on-ios)

Comment: Thank you, and apologies for my lack of knowledge but where am I to implement @obj functions and override function when I have used struct and not classes?

Comment: Update: for @objc func willResignActive() {
            disableIgnoreSilentSwitch(webView)
        } I have an error when passing wkWebView paramater. The error says Cannot convert value of type '(WKWebView, WKNavigation?) -> ()' to expected argument type 'WKWebView'

Answer (score 2):

I struggled to find a solution, and @Asperi's answer worked for me.

For the record, I was setting the configuration directly to the webView, like this, and it did not work:

```
webView.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
```

declaring the webView with the configuration object solved the issue, like this:

```
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
```