# How to disable iOS Webview going full screen on video play

Tags: ios, html5-video, vimeo

I am trying to play inline video embedded inside iOS native app.

Whatever I do, the player keeps entering full screen automatically once the video is played.

I was trying all mentioned suggestions such as `playsinline` , `allowfullscreen="false"`, `controls="false"` etc.

Is there a way to prevent iOS webview from entering full screen?

Comment: Did you find any solution for the above one?

Comment: @NensiKardani have you found a solution?

Comment: Nope. It will always play in full screen on iOS. It's a system feature so you can't change it.

Answer (score 4):

You can enable inline playback in an iOS web view via configuration in your code, using WKWebViewConfiguration and allowsInlineMediaPlayback:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/1614793-allowsinlinemediaplayback

> Set this property to true to play videos inline, or false to use the native full-screen controller. When adding a video element to an HTML document on iPhone, you must also include the playsinline attribute.
> The default value of this property is false for iPhone and true for iPad.

You can see an example in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59834721/334402

Answer (score 4):

### Swift  5.5

You just need `allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true`

```
class WebViewConfigurator {

    private var _webViewConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()

    var webKitConfig : WKWebViewConfiguration {
        _webViewConfig
    }

    init() {
        _webViewConfig.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me.