# why vimeo HTML player interrupt my app audio session?

Tags: ios, html5-video, wkwebview, vimeo, vimeo-player

In my app(audio base app), i'm playing remote audio.

before start playing i set following category

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [])
```

so while i'm playing audio, i also play vimeo video in `WKWebView` which cause audio interrupt. how to avoid this behaviour?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
        <style type="text/css">
        body, html {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;background:black}
        .main {position: absolute;top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; background-color: #101010;height:100%;}
        .main iframe {display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;}
        </style>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
        <div class="main">
        <iframe src=\(url)></iframe>
        </div>

        <script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
        <script>
        var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
        var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

        player.on('play', function() {
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.play.postMessage("play")
        });

        player.on('pause', function() {
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.pause.postMessage("pause")
        });

        player.on('ended', function(data) {
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.ended.postMessage("ended")
        });

        player.on('bufferstart', function(data) {
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.bufferstart.postMessage("bufferstart")
        });

        player.on('bufferend', function(data) {
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.bufferend.postMessage("bufferend")
        });

        Promise.all([player.getVideoWidth(), player.getVideoHeight()]).then(function(dimensions) {
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.dimensions.postMessage(dimensions)
        });

        player.getDuration().then(function(duration) {
            window.webkit.messageHandlers.duration.postMessage(duration);
        });

        player.ready().then(function () {
        player.setVolume(1)
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.ready.postMessage("ready");
        });

        function play() {
        player.play();
        }

        function pause() {
        player.pause();
        }

        function destroy() {
        player.destroy();
        }

        </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You are using the wrong category - try `AVAudioSessionCategory.ambient` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The interruption happens because `WKWebview` sound is handled by different process and a separate `AVAudioSession`. The `WKWebview` AVAudioSessionCategory category will switch to `.playback` while the sounds is playing either through `<audio>` or `<video>` tags (or its javascript counterparts). This must be the underlying mechanism that your vimeo playback uses (otherwise the interrupts would not occur).

There are 2 main routes you can go:

1) If you're ok with your main app sounds(not the `WKWebView` ones) mixing with any other iOS sounds (like the iPod music playback) then go with @Rog 's suggestion from the comment to use `.ambient` for your main app audiosession category. (This will also cause your app main audio session not to emit sound while the hardware silent switch is in off position).

2) A more flexible but requiring careful timing handling is to additionally set `.mixWithOthers` options for your main app audiosession `.playback` category. You would remove `.mixWithOthers` once you detect `WKWebView` is done playing it's own sound. From user perspective it would appear as your app is using `.playback` all the time.

I covered somewhat related topic in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56460400/5329717)